# More nice code for grepping element in list of list

Tags: python

I am looking for nice alternative for this part of code:

```
    def reportResult (finalParsResult):

        print "Total Number of Mimatch Files:", 
        diffSum=0
        for (gP, matchFiles, diffFiles, matchFolders, gpExtrFld, upExtraFldrs) in FinalResult:
            diffSum=diffSum+len(diffFiles)
        print "Number of diff files", diffSum
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: If you don't need the other unpacked variables in your for loop, you can do: `for for (_, _, diffFiles, _, _, _) in FinalResult:`. This would reduce the overall verbosity of the code.

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and [help/on-topic], this sort of question is too vague and opinion-based to be on-topic on [so]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def reportResult(finalParsResult):
    return sum(len(result_row[2]) for result_row in FinalResult)
```

Or, if `FinalResult` should actually be the parameter `finalParsResult`:

```
def reportResult(finalParsResult):
    return sum(len(result_row[2]) for result_row in finalParsResult)
```